# Can you help me with this SQL query? My professor couldn't figure it out and suggested that I post here

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL statement that is trying to find the customer who has purchased the most books and the total number of books they have purchased. The relevant relations and attributes are:

```
CUSTOMER (Cust_ID, FName, LName)
PURCHASE_ORDER (Cust_ID, Order_ID)
BOOK_ORDER (Order_ID)
```

The SQL statement that is giving me the error is:

```
SELECT C.FName, C.LName, COUNT(B.Order_ID)
FROM CUSTOMER AS C,
PURCHASE_ORDER AS P,
BOOK_ORDER AS B
WHERE P.Order_ID = B.Order_ID
   AND P.Cust_ID = C.Cust_ID
   AND COUNT (B.Order_ID) = (SELECT MAX(NUM_BOOKS)
                             FROM (SELECT COUNT(B.Order_ID) AS NUM_BOOKS

                                   WHERE P.Cust_ID = C.Cust_ID
                                      AND B.Order = P.Order_ID
                                   GROUP BY C.Cust_ID
                                  )
                            );
```

> /#1064 - you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to user near ') LIMIT 0, 25' at line 9

Comment: The error is referring to text that is not part of the query posted.

Comment: there is a `select` without a `from`.

Comment: You should refrain from unqualified joins and use ```INNER, LEFT or RIGHT JOIN```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines, though I 100% agree with the comments posted so far... This seems like homework.

```
SELECT
      C.Cust_ID
    , COUNT(B.Order_ID) AS TOTAL_BOOKS
FROM CUSTOMER C
LEFT JOIN PURCHASE_ORDER P ON P.Cust_ID = C.Cust_ID
LEFT JOIN BOOK_ORDER B ON B.Order_ID = P.Order_ID

GROUP BY C.Cust_ID
ORDER BY COUNT(B.Order_ID) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @CaiusJard Good call. I merely looked at the tags and only saw 'sql'. Corrected the post.